# Android RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: java, android, json

I created this application to get the wether details to my app.

I have a `GetWeather Class` in my Android App in which I have a constructor that I pass my current city and state.

```
GetWeather weather = new GetWeather(city_send,state_code);
```

The constructor then pings an API URL with required city, state and API credentials to receive a weather data json as response. But when i run the app it stops saying Unable to instantiate activity.

Main Activity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showData);

            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetWeather.class);
                GetWeather  gw = new GetWeather("CA","Anuradhapura");

                    startActivity(nextScreen);
                }
            });
        }

GetWeather class


import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
...
...

import android.util.Log;  


public class GetWeather {


    private static String WEATHER_URL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/key/conditions/q/";

    public String weather;
    public String temperature_string;
    public Bitmap weather_icon;

    public GetWeather() {

    }
    public  GetWeather(String city, String state){

        city = city.replaceAll(" ", "_");
        //construct post URL
        final String GET_WEATHER_URL = WEATHER_URL + state + "/" + city + ".json";  
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                String request = GET_WEATHER_URL;
                HttpResponse rp = null;
                JSONObject jObject = null;
                try {
                    rp = (new DefaultHttpClient()).execute(new HttpPost(request));
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (rp != null && rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    Log.i("Get Weather", "Success");
                    HttpEntity entity = rp.getEntity();
                    InputStream is = null;
                    try {
                        is = entity.getContent();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NullPointerException n1){
                        n1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    final char[] buffer = new char[0x10000];
                    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
                    Reader in = null;
                    String json_string_response = null;
                    try {
                        in = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NullPointerException n1){
                        n1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    int read = 0;
                    do {
                        try {
                            read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NullPointerException n1){
                            n1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (read>0) {
                            out.append(buffer, 0, read);
                        }
                    } while (read>=0);

                    try {
                        is.close();
                        json_string_response = out.toString();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        jObject = new JSONObject(json_string_response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    try {



                         JSONObject current_observation = jObject.getJSONObject("current_observation");
                         weather = current_observation.getString("weather"); 
                         temperature_string = current_observation.getString("temperature_string");
                         String icon_url = current_observation.getString("icon_url");
                         weather_icon = get_weather_icon(icon_url);


                    } catch (JSONException e4) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e4.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else{
                        String response = rp.toString().toString();
                        Log.e("Get Weather", response);
                }

            }
        }).start();     
    }

    public static Bitmap get_weather_icon(String url){
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;

        try {

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;

    }

}
```

LogCat view

```
03-20 04:48:01.544: D/AndroidRuntime(1074): Shutting down VM
03-20 04:48:01.554: W/dalvikvm(1074): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-20 04:48:01.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 04:48:01.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1074): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jsonapp/com.example.jsonapp.GetWeather}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.jsonapp.GetWeather cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
03-20 04:48:01.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
03-20 04:48:01.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-20 04:48:01.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-20 04:48:01.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-20 04:48:01.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 04:48:01.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 04:48:01.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-20 04:48:01.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method
```

Edit:

```
  {
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "conditions": 1
  }
    }
  , "current_observation": {
        "image": {
        "url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title":"Weather Underground",
        "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        "display_location": {
        "full":"Anuradhapura, Sri Lanka",
        "city":"Anuradhapura",
        "state":"",
        "state_name":"Sri Lanka",
        "country":"SB",
        "country_iso3166":"LK",
        "zip":"00000",
        "magic":"1",
        "wmo":"43421",
        "latitude":"8.32999992",
        "longitude":"80.41999817",
        "elevation":"89.00000000"
        },
        "observation_location": {
        "full":"Anuradhapura, ",
        "city":"Anuradhapura",
        "state":"",
        "country":"Sri Lanka",
        "country_iso3166":"LK",
        "latitude":"8.33333302",
        "longitude":"80.41666412",
        "elevation":"322 ft"
        },
        "estimated": {
        },
        "station_id":"43421",
        "observation_time":"Last Updated on March 20, 8:30 AM IST",
        "observation_time_rfc822":"Thu, 20 Mar 2014 08:30:00 +0530",
        "observation_epoch":"1395284400",
        "local_time_rfc822":"Thu, 20 Mar 2014 11:08:59 +0530",
        "local_epoch":"1395293939",
        "local_tz_short":"IST",
        "local_tz_long":"Asia/Colombo",
        "local_tz_offset":"+0530",
        "weather":"Scattered Clouds",
        "temperature_string":"83 F (28 C)",
        "temp_f":83,
        "temp_c":28,
        "relative_humidity":"73%",
        "wind_string":"Calm",
        "wind_dir":"",
        "wind_degrees":0,
        "wind_mph":0,
        "wind_gust_mph":0,
        "wind_kph":0,
        "wind_gust_kph":0,
        "pressure_mb":"1012",
        "pressure_in":"29.89",
        "pressure_trend":"",
        "dewpoint_string":"76 F (24 C)",
        "dewpoint_f":76,
        "dewpoint_c":24,
        "heat_index_string":"NA",
        "heat_index_f":"NA",
        "heat_index_c":"NA",
        "windchill_string":"NA",
        "windchill_f":"NA",
        "windchill_c":"NA",
        "feelslike_string":"83 F (28 C)",
        "feelslike_f":"83",
        "feelslike_c":"28",
        "visibility_mi":"12.0",
        "visibility_km":"20.0",
        "solarradiation":"--",
        "UV":"-1","precip_1hr_string":" in ( mm)",
        "precip_1hr_in":"",
        "precip_1hr_metric":"--",
        "precip_today_string":" in ( mm)",
        "precip_today_in":"",
        "precip_today_metric":"--",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "forecast_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/43421.html",
        "history_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/43421/2014/3/20/DailyHistory.html",
        "ob_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=8.33333302,80.41666412"
    }
}
```

Comment: It is definetely one of the worst approaches to load data asynchronously this way. The problem is, it appears that you will wish to access some data of `GetWeather` class from one of your `Activities`, but this could lead you to `NullPointerException`, as your data could not be yet loaded (it is loaded in a separate thread asynchronously). There are approaches for handling this situation, `AsyncTask`, `Handler` and some other. Pay attention.

Comment: Thanks for your commetnt sir. i used AsyncTask earlier and had no luck. Thats why i am doing it in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.jsonapp/com.example.jsonapp.GetWeather}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.jsonapp.GetWeather cannot be
>   cast to android.app.Activity

```
public class GetWeather {
```

`GetWeather` is not a Activity class

You have

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetWeather.class);
GetWeather  gw = new GetWeather("CA","Anuradhapura");
startActivity(nextScreen);
```

You only need

```
GetWeather  gw = new GetWeather("CA","Anuradhapura");
```

and remove the other 2 lines

Edit:

```
public class GetWeather { 


private static String WEATHER_URL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/706d22f330042323/conditions/q/"; 

public String weather; 
public String temperature_string; 
public Bitmap weather_icon; 

public GetWeather() { 

} 
public GetWeather(String city, String state){ 

city = city.replaceAll(" ", "_"); 
//construct post URL 
final String GET_WEATHER_URL = WEATHER_URL + state + "/" + city + ".json"; 
new Thread(new Runnable() 
{ 
public void run() 
{ 
String request = GET_WEATHER_URL; 
HttpResponse rp = null; 
JSONObject jObject = null; 
try 
{ 
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1); 
HttpGet request1 = new HttpGet("http://api.wunderground.com/api/706d22f330042323/conditions/q/CA/Anuradhapura.json"); 
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request1); 
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity(); 
String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); 
jObject = new JSONObject(_response); 
JSONObject current_observation = jObject.getJSONObject("current_observation"); 
weather = current_observation.getString("weather"); 
Log.i("..............",""+weather); 
temperature_string = current_observation.getString("temperature_string"); 
String icon_url = current_observation.getString("icon_url"); 
weather_icon = get_weather_icon(icon_url); 

}catch(Exception e) 
{ 
e.printStackTrace(); 
} 


} 
}).start(); 
} 

public static Bitmap get_weather_icon(String url){ 
Bitmap bitmap = null; 
InputStream in = null; 
BufferedOutputStream out = null; 

try { 

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent()); 

} catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
} 

return bitmap; 

} 

}
```

The log:

```
03-20 02:16:46.273: I/..............(1358): Mostly Cloudy
```

Comment: @user2781812 no need for that. have `GetWeather  gw = new GetWeather("CA","Anuradhapura");`

Comment: sir i did what you said but then i get no Empty constructor error. althouth i have a empty constructor there

Comment: @user2781812 you don't need a empty constructor. You pass 2 args and the constructor has 2 args.  `GetWeather  gw = new GetWeather("CA","Anuradhapura");` and this `public  GetWeather(String city, String state){`

Comment: Thank you sir. i got throuth it. now i get json error.JSONException: No value for current_observation

Comment: if you can tell me a way to get rid of it i would highly appreciate it sir

Comment: @user2781812 there is a problem in json parsing.

Comment: If you will extend your GetWhether class with Activity you will get 03-20 01:29:36.500: E/AndroidRuntime(2115): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?) exception

Comment: i have internet pernission sir. but unable to get json data. please help

Comment: @user2781812 1. open the link in the browser. make sure its a valid url. 2. post the json here.

Comment: @user2781812 link is dead

Comment: i added the full link too. can you please tell me where i got wrong sir. Thank you

Comment: @user2781812 the parsing looks fine

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50091/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user2781812)

Comment: Thanks for the all the help sir. i only have a one issue with this code. i tried to return a value to main by making the GetWeather return a string. but it always returns a null. how can i fix it sir? plese be kind enogh to reply me sir.

Comment: @user2781812 pls post a new question for a new problem

Answer (score 1):

you have this:

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetWeather.class);
```

GetWeather is not an activity class hence you cannot pass this to the method of Intent. Change it to Activity class by extending GetWeahter to activity.

Comment: there is no need for `GetWeahter` to be a Activity class

Comment: i got through it. Any idea of this error sir JSONException: No value for current_observation

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GetWeather {
}
```

**Since your not extending `Activity` in `GetWeather` class you cant state that class has a activity.**

You **must** extend the `Activity` class to `GetWeather` class as shown below.

```
public class GetWeather extends Activity {
}
```

I would rather suggest you to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)